# How can i sort by a string property but not alphabetically

Tags: c#, compare

i have an object that has a string property called "Status".  I have a collection of these objects and want to order a collection by that field which is a string.

the possible values of Status are:

"Open", "Closed", "Pending"  so i can't use alphabetic order.  What is the best way to say that "Open" is greater than "Closed" which is greater than "Pending" ?

I know there is an IComparer<> interface but i want to see the most elegant way to define the order of various strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using an Enum instead of a string?

```
     public enum Status
     {
        Pending,
        Closed,
        Open
      }
```

Then Open > Closed > Pending

You can also use Jon Skeet's answer to convert your string to an enum, if you can't change the fact that you're returning string.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a mapping of *some* form, from the string to some naturally sortable value (e.g. integer).

Then you can use:

```
var sorted = unsorted.OrderBy(x => ConvertStatusToInt32(x.Status));
```

The conversion method might use a statically-initialized `Dictionary`, or a switch, or whatever.

(You might want to consider using an enum, by the way - ideally for your original status. That way you don't need to rely on strings at all.)

Comment: Maybe use the enum offered by @Yuf in his answer as the map, then use enum.Parse() in place of ConvertStatusToInt32?

Comment: @Steve: I would probably use Unconstrained Melody myself, but `enum.Parse` would do too :) It would be better to change the property type though...

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem here is that your trying to force semantics on to the string class.  If I were you, I'd create my own status object:

```
public class Status : IComparable
{
    private string statusText_ = string.Empty;
    private int priority_ = 0;

    public class Status(string text, int priority)
    {
        statusText_ = text;
        priority_ = priority;
    }

    // accessors ...


    public int CompareTo(object o)
    {
           // add compare logic to compare priorities here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define the order here:

```
string[] bestOrder = new string[] { "Open", "Closed", "Pending" };
```

Then sort by the index of (i.e. `IndexOf`) the string in question in `bestOrder`.

Depending on how you are sorting the code will vary.. but a delegate to do `x => bestOrder.IndexOf(x)` or similar is probably what you want.

Comment: how would i then use that in the comparison ?

Comment: You dont need to.  Do `list.OrderBy(x => bestOrder.IndexOf(x));` and that's it

Answer (score 0):

If it's a static finite collection of options you could replace the string with an enumeration and sort on the integer value of the enumeration .